# Java, юнит тесты для void методов выводящих строки

Tags: java, юнит-тесты

Как тестировать такие методы, даже не знаю как подойти к ним

[image: void methods]

Comment: После выполнения метода читать из консоли ( удобно классом Scanner ) и проверять, что все правильно

Comment: никак, вы сами убиваете эту возможность через жесткий линк на System.out. Вам нужно прокидывать соответствующий интерфейс как зависимость через конструктор, и в тестах смотреть, что в этот интерфейс поступило то что нужно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если тестируеумый код недоступен для изменения, либо его не желательно менять в данный момент, то можете переопределить стандартный вывод при инициализации теста, да вернуть его обратно после выполнения:

```
// в setUp
testOutput = new PrintStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream());
System.setOut(testOutput);

String actual = testOutput.toString();
assertThat(actual).contains("something");

// в tearDown
PrintStream normalOutput = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out));
System.setOut(normalOutput);
```

Ну а вообще, как и говорил [Etki](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/u/16095) в комментариях - по нормальному, здесь нужен рефакторинг тестируемого кода с заменой `System.out.print()` на метод из внешней зависимости, реализацию которой впоследствии можно будет легко подменить через аргумент конструктора тестируемого класса, его свойства, либо через IoC-контейнер.

Comment: А зачем вызывается два конструктора `PrintStream` подряд?

Comment: @Yukon, опечатка - одного вполне достаточно :)